Retrieve the latest record for a given user from the database
which way is better? and why?
queryset = Tariff.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created_at').first()

or
queryset = Tariff.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('created_at').last()

You need to get the newest record from the database, which way is better and faster?

Share your Tariff model.

What were the results when you tested them?

The two are equivalent. Indeed, if we look at the implementation [GitHub] of the .last() method [Django-doc]:

def last(self):
    """Return the last object of a query or None if no match is found."""
    if self.ordered:
        queryset = self.reverse()
    else:
        self._check_ordering_first_last_queryset_aggregation(method="last")
        queryset = self.order_by("-pk")
    for obj in queryset[:1]:
        return obj

This will change the ordering of the query, so if you did ORDER BY some_column ASC, it will now show ORDER BY some_column DESC. So both will result in the same query.
Note however that:
queryset = Tariff.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created_at').first()
is not a QuerySet, it is Tariff object, or None if no such object is present.
You can write this a bit more shorter by using:
tariff = Tariff.objects.filter(user=user).latest('created_at')
which will raise a Tariff.DoesNotExist exception if there is no Tariff object for that user, but these all will produce the same SQL query.
If not yet done, you can add a database index on the created_at field with db_index=True [Django-doc], this will make queries typically a lot faster.
